# method deleteQuietly(File) undefined for type FileUtils

Tags: java

I am studying a code already written, but there are still some mistake when I compile it with Eclipse on my computer.

One of those error is for the following method, and other ones also

```
private static void deleteFile(File baseDir, String name) {
    File file = new File(baseDir, name);
    if (file.exists()){
        FileUtils.deleteQuietly(file);
}
```

}

I have added the jar org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils to my buildpath and imported it in my class so I don't think it is coming from there, but I don't know why it is not working. I've checked and deleteQuietly is indeed a method from the class FileUtils. Help me please

Thank you

Comment: You get the error "method deleteQuietly(File) undefined for type FileUtils" but you don't think it's coming from FileUtils? You should probably go back on that assumption. Please show your `import` statements for both `FileUtils` and `File`.

Answer (score 1):

The method `deleteQuietly(File file)` is defined since version **1.4**.

Check the version of Apache Commons that you imported.